# How to add objects to ArrayList from main?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, program-entry-point

So I have a class called Persons that the moment has a method to add Person objects when created in main.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Persons {

public ArrayList<Person> personsList = new ArrayList<Person>();

   public boolean addPerson(Person newPerson) {
       personsList.add(newPerson);
       return true;
   }
}
```

This is my main method

```
import java.util.*;

public class testPersons {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Persons persons = new Persons();

    Address person1Address = new Address(xxx, "xxx", "xxx", "CA", "xxx");
    Address person1JobAddress = new Address(1542, "High St", "Santa Cruz", "CA", "94063");
    ArrayList<String> person1Phone = new ArrayList<String>();
    person1Phone.add("xxx-xxx-xxx");
    Job person1Job = new Job("Teacher", 25000.00, person1JobAddress);
    Person person1 = new Person("xxxxxxx", "San Mateo", 'M', person1Address, person1Job, person1Phone);

    persons.addPerson(person1);

    System.out.println(persons);
   }
}
```

So my question is, "How would I add the object Persons1 into my arrayList in Persons class?" It does compile, but I when run it, I get weird gibberish. Would it be I'm missing something in my Persons class, main or can I not print the objects in ArrayList like I did?

Comment: Printing an object, by default, will just print the `hashCode()` of the object.  If you want it to loop through the object and print all the objects it contains, you need to write code to do that.

Comment: You printing the "default" results of `Persons`. The general suggestion will be to override `toString`, personally I find this a bad idea, `toString` should be reserved for debugging.  In your case, you could just iterate over the `personsList` instead

Comment: why on earth should `toString()` be reserved for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your `Person` related classes including `Person` override the default toString().

when you System.out.println(persons), this happens:

- The `Person` objects in your ArrayList are called one by one.
- For each `Person` object, its `toString()` is method is called. If `toString()` is not overridden, the `Object` (default) `toString` will be called. Hence the "weird gibberish". You need to tell java what kind of "presentation" you would like to show by overriding the `toString()`